# How can I disable Resharper's rename command?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I want to restore Visual Studio's built-in rename command, because when I try to rename a variable using resharper, half the time when I press enter to complete the rename it tries putting a newline in the variable name, making a mess of all my code. Can I disable just this one feature? Or have they fixed this recently? It's very annoying.

Comment: @That's fair. Maybe I'm to hard on that ratio :) keep up the good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper 5.1.3 that is currently the [official ReSharper download](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) doesn't show the kind of behavior that you're referring to.
I wonder which version of ReSharper and which version of Visual Studio are you using, and how long have you experienced this problem?
Also, you can try pressing "Tab" instead of "Enter" to complete the rename action.

Comment: It's Resharper 5 and VS 2010... I don't know the exact versions, I can check when I get home. It doesn't happen 100% of the time, but often enough to be frustrating. I'll try pressing tab instead and see if that works.